# SQL Server 2008: Update Statement: How to decrement a column for every 10000 records found in query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a huge table called Items

```
P_ID    Item             Rank
1       ItemName1        ValueTBD
```

I need to be able to write an update statement to populate the value of the column "rank" as follows:

- The top 10000 records need a value of "10"
- For Each subsequent 10000 records the value of "rank" will need to be decremented by 1

Therefore records 20000 - 30000 : would have "rank" values of "9"

Comment: Should it ever go negative?  If not what do you do for 10000-11000?

Comment: ah good question yes, hten the number would be -1

Comment: Whenever you need to persist such a transient information like the row rank in a specific order, is a clear indication of a design problem. Updating the table to set the rank is extremely expensive, and the rank is obsolete after the very first insert or delete, and often after an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that when you say 'top' and 'subsequent' you actually imply 'order by `P_ID`':

```
with cte as (
 select Rank, row_number() over (order by P_ID) as row_rank
  from Items)
update cte
  set Rank = 10 - (row_rank-1)/10000;
```

This will update with right range boundary (1-10000 -> rank 10, 10001-20000 - >rank 9, 20001-30000 -> rank 8 etc) and will assign negative ranks for ranges above 100001. Your requirements are inconsistent: you say 'records 20000-30000 would have rank 9'. You probably mean 'records 20001-30000 would have rank 8'.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on updating a table through a CTE?  I hadn't heard of this before and I can't seem to find anything on MSDN.

Comment: @Abe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx `After a CTE is defined, it can be referenced like a table or view can in a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement. A CTE can also be used in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of its defining SELECT statement.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT P_ID,Rank, 10 - ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY P_ID DESC))/10000) AS new_RANK
```

Comment: is there an easy to stop the decrement at 1 and have every record after 10000 = 1?

Comment: Use this query as a subselect. When retrieving `new_RANK`, substitute every value less than 2 with 1: `CASE WHEN new_RANK < 2 THEN 1 ELSE new_RANK END AS ...`